# How to merge Two data sets of point clouds or polygons into one? (Merging not Appending)

Tags: vtk, scanning, point-clouds, point-cloud-library, 3d-reconstruction

I am developing a real-time scanner, in which I would be able to scan the surface in real-time. Untill now I can scan one patch of the surface and can save it.
One patch means just 1 scan of the surface (point cloud or triangles).

What I want is, I want to scan multiple patches in real-time. For this purpose, I have to merge the previous patch with the current patch. But I don't know what is the standard way or algorithm to merge two patches and also I don't know which one is the best way for merging, for example, before triangulation (point cloud merging), or after the triangulation (mesh merging).
Merging means remove overlapped points or triangles

My idea: If there are two point clouds, source and target then using VTK, find a closest point from the target point cloud, and select one point the other is discarded. Is this a method for merging ? This is just my idea?
But the problem is, the number of points in source and target will be different.

How can I merge two patches using VTK, kindly guide me?

Also suggest me what is the standard and optimum way to achieve real-time scanning task.

**Case # 1:**
i) Point Cloud Aquisition

ii) Register

iii) Merge

iv) Triangulate

**Case # 2:**

i) Point Cloud Aquisition

ii) Register

iii) Triangulate

iv) Merge

**Case # 3:**

i) Point Cloud Aquisition

ii) Triangulate

iii)Register

iv) Merge

Please guide me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put a note here because I have just been thinking about something similar.

Your suggested method (doing a nearest neighbour search during the merge) does seem possible. The issue about there being different sizes between the two clouds being merged does not seem to be an issue if you do a radius search based on some desirable resolution rather than a search for 1 neighbour.

To manage your case 1, you could try merging all the clouds then downsampling with a voxel grid e.g. pcl::VoxelGrid before the triangulation (this would be the easiest way but may not be what you want).

The algorithm encapsulated in pcl::GreedyProjectionTriangulation seems to be mostly described in the below paper [1]. In that paper they also describe an incremental mesh update procedure which is a minor change to the algorithm (they remove triangles close to a new point and start the greedy triangulation again). As far as I know, this has not been implemented in PCL but shouldn't be too difficult. This would correspond to your case 2. However, the mesh you get out would depend on the order in which you merged the clouds. Because it is a time investment I would suggest trying the point-based merging first.

[1] Marton, Z. C., R. B. Rusu, and M. Beetz. 2009. “On Fast Surface Reconstruction Methods for Large and Noisy Point Clouds.” In IEEE International Conference On Robotics and Automation, 3218–3223. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5152628.

Comment: I hv been trying to understand your answer and paper.
It really helped me a lot to understand some concepts. By the way do you have any idea about what professional companies do for real-time scanning. I have seen one Intraoral Scanner in which incremental surface is reconstructed and only unique points is inserted into the surface. There was not any kind of overlapping. What do you think what are they doing. Means that first they get one patch of the point cloud, then transform, then second patch, then register, then merge both patches using closest neighbor, then triangular, then display.

Comment: This loop continues until exit. The only problem I am thinking is, if I do not move the camera and continue scanning only one specific surface, then you see, the second patch will be same as the first one, only few points different due to some error or whatever. so it means that if I have 100 points in the first patch and 70 in the second then the final surface should have 110 points, 60 should be discarded because of overlapping. for this purpose which method should be feasible, optimum and fast. I have a full system in which I can scan the surface.

Comment: Now I just need to make it incremental in real-time.

Comment: Regarding your first question; I do not know what companies do. Presumably each comes up with its own solution and the lessons learned I expect remain propriety! It is not something I have done; only thought about. The solutions you listed do seem reasonable. I am familiar with PCL and I have heard of MeshLab - that's all!

Comment: Regarding the issue of speed; if you can select a desirable mesh resolution (possibly close to your effective sensor resolution) then you can use that to throw away points that are close to your mesh or point cloud (because after all a mesh is just a point cloud with edges). This would be done fast with e.g. a voxel grid. Since the triangulation is possibly the slowest part you probably don't want to re-triangulate frequently, so I would try to register against the mesh vertices. If there is too great a difference in resolution, I'd suggest keeping the cloud at multiple resolutions.

Comment: Though I don't know how you are doing the triangulation; it can be pretty fast too.